# Having trouble reading, writing, and recalculating values in a dictionary dynamically

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to recalculate stats that are variables when any time the file is called (or, ideally, only upon serving that monster's entry), but I need to not overwrite areas like "Replicated Replicator Replica" when that happens. Additionally, I need to be able to overwrite the latter with a method in another file. Here is an example code snippet

```
import random

class stat_tracker:
    stat_class_hp = 1000

class monsters:
    all_monsters = {
        "Sewer": {
            1: {"Name": "The Beast",
                "HP": 4500,
                },
        },
        "Tourney 1": {
            1: {
                "Name": "Simon Sais",
                "HP": stat_tracker.stat_class_hp * 2,
            },
        },
        "Replicated Replicator Replica": {
            1: {"NUL"}
        },
    }

def combat_encounter_roller(current_zone):
    for zone_name, zone_monsters in monsters.all_monsters.items():
        if zone_name == current_zone:
            return zone_monsters[1]

class current_zone:
    name = ""


class current_monster:
    whole_monster = {}
    monster_name = "Test"
    monster_hp = 0

def initialize_monster_stats(zone):
    monster = combat_encounter_roller(zone)
    current_monster.whole_monster = monster
    current_monster.monster_name = monster["Name"]
    current_monster.monster_hp = monster["HP"]



def use_battle_item():
    # setting the value rather than going through figuring out if you have the item and what its effects are.
    effect_name = "Replicator Replicate"
    if effect_name == "Replicator Replicate":
        monsters.all_monsters["Replicated Replicator Replica"][1] = current_monster.whole_monster.copy()
        print("You quickly scanned the monster and made a copy!")

#
def combat_prompt(zone):
    current_zone.name = zone
    initialize_monster_stats(zone)
    use_battle_item()
#
print(monsters.all_monsters["Replicated Replicator Replica"][1])
combat_prompt("Tourney 1")
stat_tracker.stat_class_hp *= 2
combat_prompt("Tourney 1")
stat_tracker.stat_class_hp *= 2
print(stat_tracker.stat_class_hp * 2, current_monster.monster_hp, "These two values should be equal")
print(monsters.all_monsters["Replicated Replicator Replica"][1])
```

I have tried a few different avenues and asked a friend familiar with Python. Basically, the bind is as follows:

- I can put it in a method so it calculates the variable stats whenever it is called, but then it is not accessible to write to outside the method, and reverts changes when the method ends/I call it again.
- I can put it in a class, but then it initializes all the stats equal to their starting values. Unfortunately, I need them to recalculate on the fly, not just on startup.

It feels like this should be possible, but I just cannot figure out how to do it.

I can also add a code snippet where I show making the stats update but fail to be able to update the replicator zone, if needed.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to use `all_monsters["Replicated Replicator Replica"][1] = <some monster>`?

Comment: You should be passing variables explicitly to the `use_battle_item()` function. It's hard to tell from what you've posted if you're passing variables or using the global ones, but if you're misunderstanding variable scope, that might cause the issue.  Try the examples here: https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_functions.asp Also see https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_scope.asp

Comment: Yes, @mkrieger1, I need to be able to set that. I know how to do that, I just can't figure out how to do that while also recalculating the stats that are equal to variables. It seems like I can get one or the other to work, but not both. Either I can set the values in the dictionary when I use a Replicator, or  can make the stats recalculate when I call it. I am a bit stuck on how I can accomplish both of these at once.

Comment: I don't understand yet what is the "other" thing you need to do as well. What does it mean to "recalculate stats that are equal to variables"? Which stats? Which variables? Why can't you do one of these things but not both?

Comment: If the links I've put in above don't clarify things, we're probably missing important pieces of the code - and you've deleted some of it for brevity.  Please see this advice on creating a small, reproducible example, so we can clearly see the issue you're getting: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Sorry, for being a bit unclear. I have some stats, like Simon Sais' HP, which are equal to a variable that changes during the game, the monster scales with you. Other monsters, like The Beast, have stats that are static. I need to be able to recalculate the stats that scale, but they don't always scale at the same rate. I also need to be able to write to all_monsters["Replicated Replicator Replica"][1]. 

The issue is that I only know how to get one or other to work. I cannot get it to calculate scaling stats without overwriting the new value of the replicator @mkrieger1

Comment: How do you calculate scaling stats so that the new value of the replicator is overwritten? (Please show the code by [edit]ing your question)

Comment: @SarahMesser here is a paste of a minimal example, which shows Simon's HP not updating with the changing player HP, but me successfully updating the dictionary. If needed, I can also produce one where the stats update but the dictionary cannot be permanently updated when copying a monster.

https://pastebin.com/USA1aFhr

Comment: @mkrieger1 I have edited the post with an example you can run, per your and Sarah's suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

The code as written has multiple issues, likely due to you being new to programming:

- The primary cause of the problem is that you've misunderstood how variable assignments work. You have written the code as if you expect them to be true at all time, even after the state changes. This is not the case. The computer only updates variables when you explicitly tell it to do so.  As written, the HP of "Tourney 1" is set to 2000 when the class `monsters` is first read, and `monsters.all_monsters["Tourney 1"][1]["HP"]` is *never* updated.  You change `stat_tracker.stat_class_hp`, but that doesn't matter because it's only used in the calculation of `monsters.all_monsters["Tourney 1"][1]["HP"]` when the latter *first* occurs - during the `monsters` class declaration. To fix this you function which calculates the HP for a monster given `stat_tracker.stat_class_hp` and some other value which distinguishes the number of HP per monster at the same level.
- You are not distinguishing between *class* attributes and *instance* attributes.  You need to [instantiate a class](https://dev.to/ogwurujohnson/creating-and-instantiating-a-simple-class-in-python-79b) by defining (and calling) an `__init__()` method for each class. Because you are using *class* attributes for `current_monster` rather than *instance* attributes, every reference to `current_monster` references the same object, the class. This is probably why when you put it in a class, everything gets initialized at startup and not updated: You're not understanding how classes are supposed to function and how they differ from instances. [Try this tutorial](http://introtopython.org/classes.html#What-are-classes?).
- When you define functions, you are not passing explicit parameters, and are trying to modify variables [outside their scope](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_scope.asp).  Misunderstanding scope is probably why you can't pass values *out* of a method / function.  Be sure to pass all values *into* the function via its explicit parameters, and to pass values *out* of the function via the *return* statement. To avoid accidental, implicit relationships between the inside & outside of a function, make sure the variables used on the inside have different names from those on the outside.
- You seem to intend for the top-level keys in the `all_monsters` dict to be *subclasses* of `monsters`, and for the `current_monster` to be an *instance* of the `monsters` superclass - but this is not at all what you've coded. Try out [this tutorial on Python inheritance](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_inheritance.asp)

If all this seems like a lot to bite off at once, that's because it is. You seem like you are extremely new to programming, not just in Python, but in any language - and you're trying to use more-advanced tools like classes and inheritance when you're still struggling with the basics of variables and functions.  These problems are not language-specific, and once you get the hang of how Python does it, you will be better positioned to transfer the skills to other languages.

TL;DR Recommendation: Sign up for a class or online series of tutorials on Python and learn the skills in the order the instructor presents them.

Longer, more DIY recommendation if you hate organized classes:

1. Rewrite what you've got here as a single script with *no* functions and *no* classes. Just update variables in different combinations and print them out, but tell the full story of your adventure with them.  If you want random die-rolls or user input for the various encounters, code that at this stage. Your variables will be things like `replicant_hp_in_toruney_2`, `simon_hp_in_tourney`, and `beast_hp_in_sewer`, with names that explicitly reference their purpose. Your first such script should be somewhat long, and should feel very repetitive.  The feeling of "repetitive code" is a cue for later steps in the learning-to-code process.
2. Once that's working the way you want, look through the script for sequences of updates that get repeated, or which seem to belong together. Make those pieces functions on their own. Make sure you're explicit about passing variables into the functions and returning the results, as described above.
3. At this point, you'll probably see there are several functions that are similar, and a handful of variables that are frequently called with each.  Use these cues to build classes and instances associating functionality.  Different instances of the same class should behave similarly, and can change state after initialization while allowing you to re-initialize explicitly when you want to do so.